# Is it ok to answer a question with bounty myself?

Tags: discussion, support

I have posted [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47855/formula-for-one-sided-hodrick-prescott-filter).
I had set a bounty on it and I have found the answer in the meanwhile.
Can I answer it myself? There are no answers by others neither comments so far...
Thanks!

Comment: Related to: [Is it possible to give yourself reputation points?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1294/930)

Comment: @chl thanks for the link ... there does not seem to be a yes or a no - right?

Comment: Here is what I answered to a [related request](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47692/analyse-unbalanced-repeated-measures-2x2x2x2-type-ii-anova-interactions#comment92985_47692).

Comment: You're not the first [to do this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46880).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any problem with that, personally. If you happened to find a solution to your problem, this is nice to share it with other users of this site. If a bounty was started, then you can get it or wait for new replies before bounty end (if you want to award the bounty to another great answer, letting a comment beneath your question might be a good idea).

For more discussion, see some related threads on Meta SO :

- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/150510)
- [What happens to a bounty if you accept your own answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120242/150510)